# node-mongodb show update results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I `db.collection('example').update({"a":1},{"$set":{"b":2}},{multi:true},function(e,r){`

I get `r`:

```
{
n:3,
nModified:3,
ok:1
}
```

**This works, I can see If I look at my db that I have successfully updated 3 documents but where are my results?**

Quoted from https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

> **callback** is the callback to be run after the records are updated. Has three parameters, the first is an error object (if error occured), the second is the count of records that were modified, the third is an object with the status of the operation.

I've tried with 3 outputs in the callback but, then I just get `null` as a result

`db.collection('example').update({"a":1},{"$set":{"b":2}},{multi:true},function(e,n,r){`

My documents have been successfully updated but `r` is `null`!

**I am expecting for this to return my updated documents**

It doesn't look like this operation *ever does*, so how can I manullay return the documents that got changed?

Comment: The documentation doesn't state that it will return the documents that are updated, so you shouldn't really expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use findAndModify to get the updated document in the result. It's callback has 2 parameters:
 1- error
 2- Updated document

I am not sure this would work for you, but check [documentation]: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#find-and-modify for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To get the updated documents in the returned result, you'll need to use the `db.collection.bulkWrite` method instead.